# Meteor method clobbers subscribed query

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm using Meteor with React.  When I load a page, Iron Router creates a document in a collection. It then uses a Meteor.method to look up the user's permissions and set them on the document through and update.  At the same time, the client page is loading and runs queries for the document in the collection.

It seems that the Meteor.method code is clobbering the query on the client.  Through multiple queries, the document exists and I can console.log() it.  Then suddenly I get "undefined".  The document still exists because I can query it from another Meteor.call.  I have used publish/subscribe, but the client can't see it.

Here's some of my code (files combined for simplicity):

```
Editors = new Mongo.Collection('editors');

if (Meteor.isServer())
    Meteor.publish('editors', function (editorId) {
        return Editors.find(editorId) || this.ready();
    });

    Meteor.methods({
        setEditorMode: function (editorId, userId) {
            var editor = Editors.findOne(editorId);
            var role = Roles.find({
                doc_id: editor.manuscriptId,
                user_id: userId
            }).fetch()[0];
            var defaultEditorMode = "readOnly";

            if (role !== null && role.role == 'owner' || role.role == 'contributor') {
                defaultEditorMode = "readWriteComment";
            } else if (role !== null && role.role == 'reviewer') {
                defaultEditorMode = "readComment";
            }

            console.log(editor);
            Editors.update(editor._id, {
                $set: {
                    defaultEditorMode: defaultEditorMode,
                    editorMode: defaultEditorMode
                }
            });
            console.log(Editors.findOne(editor._id);
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient()) {
    Router.route('/documents/:id/edit', function () {
        var editorId;

        manuscriptId = this.params.id;

        this.wait(/* Doing some work */);

        if (this.ready()) {
            editorId = Editors.insert({manuscriptId: manuscriptId});
            Meteor.call('setEditorMode', editorId, Meteor.userId());
            this.render('editor', {
                data: function () {
                    return {
                        editorId: editorId
                    };
                }
            });
        } else {
            this.render('loading');
        }
    });

    Editor = React.createClass({
        mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

        componentWillMount: function () {
            Meteor.subscribe('editors', this.props.editorId);
        },

        getMeteorData: function () {
            var editor, editorId;

            editorId = this.props.editorId;
            editor = Editors.findOne(editorId);
            console.log(editor);

            return {
                editor: editor || {}
            };
        },

        render: function () {
            return <EditorContent editor={this.data.editor} />
        }
    });
}
```

I need to make the update on the server so that it can happen securely.  My expectation was that any updates to the document on the server would propagate to the client.  Instead, once I make the update on the server getMeteorData() gets called and the query returns "undefined".

How can I get the value I just set on the server?

Comment: Update: I've commented out the update in Meteor.methods, but I still get this problem.  In further testing, I've arranged for additional updates to the document from the client but I never get anything other than "undefined" when I query from the client (server still gets the changes).  How can I debug Meteor.subscribe?

Comment: I suppose you tried to console.log your editorId through your different components and made sure in your mongoDB/meteor shell the entry was correctly inserter and updated. Did you try to put your subscription into your getMeteorData or maybe removing || this.ready() from the publication? I'm not familiar with your style but those are the only points I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ko0stick, I figured out that I needed to place my Meteor.subscribe code inside of getMeteorData